# Several spinners with common pool point in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm practicing JavaFX by making something akin to a character creator in a RPG game. In one scene you're supposed to distribute attributes so I figured I'd apply several spinners with a common pool point. Each attribute starts at the value of 1 or 2 (depending on the race/class you choose), you can only add a specific amount of points to each attribute and there's a limited pool of points you can distribute to all the stats. The limit seems properly set, since I can't raise any stat more than the amount of points I chose, but I can still spend more points than I have, getting a negative amount of them.

```
package sample;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory;

public class CharacterCreationThreeController implements Initializable {

    //GUI elements
    @FXML private Spinner strengthSpinner;
    @FXML private Spinner enduranceSpinner;
    @FXML private Spinner dexteritySpinner;
    @FXML private Spinner intelligenceSpinner;
    @FXML private Spinner perceptionSpinner;
    @FXML private Spinner charismaSpinner;
    @FXML private Label numberOfPointsLeftLabel;


    //Set up spending points
    private final int maxPointsToSpend = 10;
    private final int maxAddStatistic = 4;
    private final IntegerProperty pointsRemaining = new SimpleIntegerProperty(maxPointsToSpend);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        // Set up player Character
        CharacterManager characterManager = new CharacterManager();
        ArrayList<PlayerCharacter> playerCharacterList = null;
        try {
            playerCharacterList = characterManager.load("save.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PlayerCharacter playerCharacter = playerCharacterList.get(playerCharacterList.size()-1);

        // Assign racial bonuses
        String playerRace = playerCharacter.getRace();
        if (playerRace.equals("Human")) playerCharacter.setCharisma(playerCharacter.getCharisma()+1);
        if (playerRace.equals("Mutant")) playerCharacter.setStrength(playerCharacter.getStrength()+1);
        if (playerRace.equals("Alien")) playerCharacter.setEndurance(playerCharacter.getEndurance()+1);
        if (playerRace.equals("Android")) playerCharacter.setIntelligence(playerCharacter.getIntelligence()+1);

        //Extract starting attributes:
        int baseStrength = playerCharacter.getStrength();
        int baseEndurance = playerCharacter.getEndurance();
        int baseDexterity = playerCharacter.getDexterity();
        int baseIntelligence = playerCharacter.getIntelligence();
        int basePerception = playerCharacter.getPerception();
        int baseCharisma = playerCharacter.getCharisma();

        //Points Left
        numberOfPointsLeftLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%d", pointsRemaining));

        //Strength Spinner
        SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory strengthValueFactory =
                new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(baseStrength, baseStrength + maxAddStatistic, baseStrength);
        strengthValueFactory.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> maxAddStatistic + baseStrength,
                pointsRemaining, strengthValueFactory.valueProperty()));
        strengthValueFactory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pointsRemaining.set(pointsRemaining.get() - newValue + oldValue));
        this.strengthSpinner.setValueFactory(strengthValueFactory);
        
        //Endurance Spinner
        IntegerSpinnerValueFactory enduranceValueFactory =
                new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(baseEndurance, baseEndurance + maxAddStatistic, baseEndurance);
        enduranceValueFactory.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> maxAddStatistic + baseEndurance,
                pointsRemaining, enduranceValueFactory.valueProperty()));
        enduranceValueFactory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pointsRemaining.set(pointsRemaining.get() - newValue + oldValue));
        this.enduranceSpinner.setValueFactory(enduranceValueFactory);
        
        //Dexterity Spinner
        IntegerSpinnerValueFactory dexterityValueFactory =
                new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(baseDexterity, baseDexterity + maxAddStatistic, baseDexterity);
        dexterityValueFactory.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> maxAddStatistic + baseDexterity,
                pointsRemaining, dexterityValueFactory.valueProperty()));
        dexterityValueFactory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pointsRemaining.set(pointsRemaining.get() - newValue + oldValue));
        this.dexteritySpinner.setValueFactory(dexterityValueFactory);
        
        //Intelligence Spinner
        IntegerSpinnerValueFactory intelligenceValueFactory =
                new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(baseIntelligence, baseIntelligence + maxAddStatistic, baseIntelligence);
        intelligenceValueFactory.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> maxAddStatistic + baseIntelligence,
                pointsRemaining, intelligenceValueFactory.valueProperty()));
        intelligenceValueFactory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pointsRemaining.set(pointsRemaining.get() - newValue + oldValue));
        this.intelligenceSpinner.setValueFactory(intelligenceValueFactory);
        
        //Perception Spinner
        IntegerSpinnerValueFactory perceptionValueFactory =
                new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(basePerception, basePerception + maxAddStatistic, basePerception);
        perceptionValueFactory.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> maxAddStatistic + basePerception,
                pointsRemaining, perceptionValueFactory.valueProperty()));
        perceptionValueFactory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pointsRemaining.set(pointsRemaining.get() - newValue + oldValue));
        this.perceptionSpinner.setValueFactory(perceptionValueFactory);
        
        //Charisma Spinner
        IntegerSpinnerValueFactory charismaValueFactory =
                new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(baseCharisma, baseCharisma + maxAddStatistic, baseCharisma);
        charismaValueFactory.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> maxAddStatistic + baseCharisma,
                pointsRemaining, charismaValueFactory.valueProperty()));
        charismaValueFactory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pointsRemaining.set(pointsRemaining.get() - newValue + oldValue));
        this.charismaSpinner.setValueFactory(charismaValueFactory);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you return from the binding is constant; the fact that there are dependencies does not change this.

You actually need to get the dependencies involved in the calculation.

Furthermore note that you repeat boilerplate code over multiple times. I strongly recommend creating a method to avoid this:

```
private void initStatSpinner(Spinner spinner, int baseValue) {
    final int fixedMax = baseValue + maxAddStatistic;

    IntegerSpinnerValueFactory valueFactory
        = new IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(baseValue, fixedMax, baseValue);

    valueFactory.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                pointsRemaining.set(pointsRemaining.get() - newValue + oldValue));

    valueFactory.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(
                () -> Math.min(fixedMax, valueFactory.getValue() + pointsRemaining.get()),
                pointsRemaining, valueFactory.valueProperty()));

    spinner.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
}
```

```
initStatSpinner(strengthSpinner, baseStrength);
initStatSpinner(dexteritySpinner, baseDexterity);
...
```

You may want to consider storing the spinners in a list though and adding the same listener to each of the value properties and use a loop to do the updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and I'll definitely rework the code to make a list of attributes. Next I want to use something similar for skills and there are even more of those.

Would you mind explaining a bit of the logic you apply to the maxProperty? I understand what's being applied to the valueProperty but not to the max one. What do the four variables inside creteIntegerBinding apply to?

Comment: @Javik Replace `fixedMax` with the RHS of the assignment, if this makes things clearer for you; I just "gave the value a name"; the values it's calculated from never change a given attribute. For the value `v` of the attribute there are 2 criteria that bound it from above: the value must not exceed the base value by more than `maxAddStatistic`, i.e. `v <= baseValue + maxAddStatistic` and the attribute must not be increased by more than the remaining points, i.e. `v <= v_current + remainingPoints`; combining both you get `v <= min(v_current + remainingPoints, baseValue + maxAddStatistic)`

Comment: I completely misunderstood how createIntegerBinging works, now I get it. Thanks.